# what framework should one use django middleware with orbit?

Tags: django, comet, orbited

The Django orbit integration methods I've seen in quick google searches don't seem to carry Django abstractions, like "request.user" with them. "request.user" is particularly important, since I am *not* going to (potentially incorrectly) re-implement session handling (this sounds like it could cause bad security bugs).

Alternatively, should I use a different server? I'd prefer to use stable, mature, popular software, that will be maintained and improved. Orbit and Django seem to be qualified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking to "integrate Django and Orbited", you might have a look here: http://github.com/clemesha/hotdot which is a very complete (but not yet polished) example of what I think you are looking for.

In particular, the example includes Authentication using Django models from the Orbited process (more specifically, Twisted Cred + Django models), as well as filtering and modifying of in-transit Orbited messages. In the example you'll find that you basically get the "request.user" object because the "request.user" object can be accessed by the cookie that Django sets + database calls using `django.contrib.sessions.models.Session` model object.